# Using Jasmine with Sublime Text 2

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine, sublimetext2

I've found a plugin to integrate jasmine testing in sublime text 2, https://github.com/gja/sublime-text-2-jasmine, but I can't make it work. It looks like a port of the TextMate plugin.

Does someone know how to make it properly work?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Actually the plugin doesn't integrate sublime with jasmine... bad luck :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to integrate? So you can run the terminal live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing said package adds is the ability to switch from a module to its spec.
You can easily and cleanly install the `Jasmine` package which does the same thing by means of using the excellent [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

Comment: I wasn't looking for that, but I guess the Jasmine package in Sublime is a highlighter. Would be nice to have TDD or BDD support in sublime hehe.
Thanks anyway